# How to use android:scaleType to show a picture

Tags: android

I use ImageView to show a picture, I want picture to show in a rect, which is smaller than its real size, but I want picture can completely show in the rect. I set other scaleType, such as 'centerInside', then the picture cannot show in the rect, but 'center' can. I wanna know that how to code that can show a picture in a rect which is smaller then itself.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="20.0dip"
        android:layout_height="20.0dip"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/boy"
        android:paddingLeft="20.0dip"
        android:paddingTop="40.0dip"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/boy" />
```

Comment: you already answer your question `" but 'center' can"`

Comment: 'center' just show part of the picture, not the full picture.

Comment: try `the android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [ImageView scale type documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html), `centerInside` also includes the padding for the size.

> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

Since your `padding` is same/bigger than the `ImageView`'s size, then the image cannot be displayed (actually, it's pushed outside the bound).

Use `android:scaleType="centerInside"` and consider to use `android:layout_margin` instead of `android:padding`.

Comment: Your advice is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Two options.-

- If the `drawable` has the same aspect ratio of your `ImageView`, set `scaleType` to `fitXY`
- Else, I'd go for `centerCrop`

Just in case you didn't know it, more about `scaleTypes` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).

Comment: I know the web site, and read it, but I don't know why using other scaleType cannot make the picture show in the rect.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `android:scaleType="centerInside"`

`public static final ImageView.ScaleType CENTER_INSIDE`

> Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding). The image is then centered in the view. From XML, use this syntax: android:scaleType="centerInside".

see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) for details

Answer (score 0):

As I undestand you have problem with using scaleType with ImageView. Put your ImageView inside (for example) FrameLayout and check my examples.

First example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">  
   <ImageView android:layout_width="200dp"  
               android:layout_height="200dp"  
               android:layout_gravity="center"  
               android:src="@drawable/something"  
               android:scaleType="centerInside">  
   </ImageView>  
 </FrameLayout>
```

Second (fullscreen scaling):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">  
   <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
               android:layout_gravity="center"  
               android:src="@drawable/something"  
               android:scaleType="centerInside">  
   </ImageView>  
 </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out image with rounded corners @ http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/

Found the below @ [How to make an ImageView with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners)

http://ruibm.com/?p=184.

```
public class ImageHelper {
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap
            .getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = pixels;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
}
```

You can also check the implementation of the demo for [RoundCornerImageView](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView)

Answer (score 0):

use scaleType="fitXY" instead of center